# What is the standard procedure to use session to access entity bean data in struts 2?

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, struts2

Suppose i have a login form as index.jsp

```
<h:form action="LoginAction" >
<h:textfield name="user" label="Login ID" /></br>
<h:password name="password" label="Password"/></br>
<h:submit value="LOGIN"/>
</h:form>
```

Here is the LoginAction.java

```
package action;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import dao.DBService;
import entity.Student;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.SessionMap;


public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport {

HttpServletRequest req;
private String user;
private String password;
Map <String,Object> session;
public void setSession(Map<String, Object> session) {
    this.session = session;

}

public String getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(String user) {
    this.user = user;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
public boolean validat() throws SQLException 
{
    String query;
    query="select * from student where user='"+user+"' and password='"+password+"'";
    ResultSet rs;
    rs=DBService.selectData(query);
    boolean status=rs.next();
    return status;

}

public String execute() throws Exception  {

    if(validat())
    {

    return SUCCESS;
    }
    return ERROR;
}
public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest hsr) {
    req = hsr;
}
}
```

And here is student.java

```
package entity;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Student {
private String name;
private String user;
private String password;
private String number;
private String country;
private String email;
private String city;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
@Id
public String getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(String user) {
    this.user = user;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getNumber() {
    return number;
}

public void setNumber(String number) {
    this.number = number;
}

public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}

public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

}
```

Now we have a jsp as Profile.jsp
In this page i want to display all the information of the student who has logged in

One way to do this is to use
'#session.context' ,but i can use this for only user and password.How to use session to access all the data from the database of that particular student.

Comment: session factory as in hibernate? could you provide me a proper link for this implementation.In examples i have come across,people have used only the name attribute to display in profile.jsp,but i haven't seen any one using database

Comment: Not sure what do you want to achieve. If you want display some user details in jsp via the session then put it into the session.

Comment: @AleksandrM suppose i want to display email of student in profile.jsp as soon as he logs in. what should i do?

Comment: @user3429506 Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have got result in ResultSet rs,you can now access the database attributes.
Like if you have attribute "role",you can access it as

```
String r=rs.getString("role");
```

and in session use

```
session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
session.put("z",r)  // value of string r in z
```

And in your profile file access this role by using

```
"#session.z"
```